# HTML/Javascript not allowing same file input twice

Tags: javascript, html, file

Hey all I have a little html code

```
<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple onchange="readSingleFile(this)">
<p align="center">
    <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick="javascript:callValidatorService();">VALIDATE</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' id="fileSelectButton">BROWSE</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick="javascript:loadSample();">SAMPLE</button>
    <button class='btn btn-primary' onclick="javascript:clearText();">CLEAR</button>
</p>

<script>
    function click(el) {
        // Simulate click on the hidden file element.
        var evt = document.createEvent('Event');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }

    document.querySelector('#fileSelectButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        //When we click the browse button, instead click the hidden file element.
        var fileInput = document.querySelector('#fileInput');
        fileInput.click();
    }, false);
</script>
```

This allows for a pop-up menu to appear to allow a user to choose a file. However it doesn't allow for multiple inputs of the same file name even if the contents of the file have changed.

Here is my javascript code that goes along with it

```
function readSingleFile(fileElement) {

    //This is how users submit a file using the browse button.
    var f = fileElement.files[0];
    if (f) {
        var r = new FileReader();
        r.onload = function(e) {
            var contents = e.target.result;
            document.getElementById("inputText").value = contents;
            callValidatorService();
        }
        r.readAsText(f);

    } else {
        alert("Failed to load file");
    }
    fileElement.files[0] = null;
    r = null;
    contents = null;
    f = null;

}
```

I thought on change only cared about the contents of the file not the file name?

Thank you

Comment: onchange responds to a change of filename. The browser quite rightly cares nothing about the content of files on your filesystem. Data is only transferred with explicit consent by the user via the input control. Don't use onchange, if you're seeking to upload revisions of the same file. Respond to a button press instead.